# What is the multiplication of two sigmas?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Say we have two sigmas $\sum_{i=0}^n\dbinom{n}{i}x^i$ and $\sum_{i=0}^m\dbinom{m}{i}x^i$, what would be the resultant of the above? How do you, in general, multiply two sigmas?

Comment: Actually, the *resultant* of two polynomials is something completely different ... and is $0$ in this special case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general solution is given by the Cauchy product:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\cdot\sum_{i=0}^m b_ix^i =\sum_{i=0}^{n+m}c_ix^i$$
where
$$c_i=\sum_{k=0}^i a_kb_{i-k}. $$

Comment: What if there was no common part?

Comment: @AayushAgrawal What do you mean by "common part"?

Comment: I mean a common factor. What would we do if there was no common factor?

Answer (score 1):

We can write them as $$(1+x)^m,(1+x)^n$$ thus there multiplication is just $$(1+x)^m\cdot (1+x)^n$$ and then perform simple indices according to the conditions

Comment: That's true but i was hoping to get a more general answer to the issue. Is there really no way to actually multiply two sigmas themselves, instead of converting it to some other form first?

Comment: Sigmas dont exhibit properties such as taking common sigma then simplifying ...